# Knockout: How to conditionally display and store a value dependent on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to conditionally update a couple of contact fields when I change a contact from a menu, but having trouble making it work. I've tried several approaches, none of which 
work well enough to even show a code example.

Here are my business rules:

**Initialize:**

- Load a list of contacts. Each contact has an Id, Name, Email and Phone.
- Load the currently-selected contact Id. Make the contact menu select the corresponding contact.
- Load the initial email value -- this may be different than the selected contact's email, as it may have been overridden and saved.
- Load the initial phone value -- this may be different than the selected contact's phone, as it may have been overridden and saved.

**Process:**

- Allow the user to change the email or phone of the currently-selected contact. This doesn't change the underlying email or phone on the contact object; instead, it's an override value.
- If the user selects a different contact from the menu, display that contact object's email and phone, replacing the previous values. The previous rule still applies: the user can then override the email or phone value of the newly-selected contact, and that override value should stick around unless the user selects a different contact from the menu.

**Persist:**

- When saving, send the currently-selected contact ID, the current value of email, and the current value of contact.

Here's a bit of my code:

**View model:**

```
function ContactViewModel( initialData ) {
    var self = this;

    // not sure I need Contacts to be an observable; I think I can use a plain array
    self.Contacts          = ko.observableArray([]); 
    self.SelectedContactId = ko.observable( null );

    self.ContactEmail      = ko.observable( null );
    self.ContactPhone      = ko.observable( null );

    // ...

    self.init() {
        // load the contacts list
        ko.utils.arrayForEach( initialData.Contacts, function( item ) {
            self.Contacts.push( { item.Id, item.Name, item.Email, item.Phone } );
        });

        // load the selected contact, email and phone
        if ( initialData.ContactInfo != null ) {
            self.SelectedContactId( initialData.ContactInfo.Id );

            if ( initialData.ContactInfo.Email != null
                && initialData.ContactInfo.Email.length > 0 ) {
                self.ContactEmail( initialData.ContactInfo.Email );
            }

            if ( initialData.ContactInfo.Phone != null
                && initialData.ContactInfo.Phone.length > 0) {
                self.ContactPhone( initialData.ContactInfo.Phone );
            }
        }
    }

    self.init();    // initialize!
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<select id="homeowner" data-bind="
    options:        Contacts,
    optionsText:    'Name',
    optionsValue:   'Id',
    optionsCaption: '-- Select a Contact --',
    value:          SelectedContactId
">
</select>

<input id="email" type="text" data-bind="value: ContactEmail" />
<input id="phone" type="text" data-bind="value: ContactPhone" />
```

It seems like I need a computed observable or two on the `ContactEmail` and `ContactPhone` that check if the `SelectedContactId` has changed, and if it has, to load the email and phone from the newly-selected contact. But I've been going in circles trying to get the `SelectedHomeownerId` to save the previous selected Id, and trying to get the `ContactEmail` to check if the current contact Id is different than the previous Id and then display the current contact's Email. What would these functions look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to SelectedContactId change and update properties as you wish:

```
self.SelectedContactId.subscribe(function (contactId){
    // find contact in your lookup:
    // then:
    self.ContactEmail('new value');
    self.ContactPhone('new value');
});
```

Comment: d'oh, it really is that simple! I've never had to subscribe() before, so I keep overlooking it. Thanks!